# How can I help these tomato plants?

Tags: plant-health, tomatoes

Some of my tomato plants are starting to wilt:

[image]

[image]

The plants in the photos are of different kinds (Roma and Lincoln tomatoes); moreover, I have other tomato plants in the same array that are thriving. What is going on with these, and how can I fix it?